# Apache Camel processing with a substring of the message

Tags: apache-camel

I want to build a Camel route that do 3 HttpRequests but in every request it should only a part of the body.

In my Message Body is this XML:

```
<part1>
...
</part1>
<part2>
...
</part2>
<part3>
...
</part3>
```

Now every Part should send to a REST-Service. The Rest-Service response with some data, this data I must put in the body of the next part. How can I solve this?

The route should like this:

```
from("activemq:inMsg")
 .setBody(xpath("//part1")).inOut("http4://localhost/workingPart1")
 .choice()
   .when()
     .replay().isEqual("ok")
     .setBody("<responsePart1>"+replay()+"</responsePart1>" + xpath("//part2")).inOut("http4://localhost/workingPart2")
     .choice()
        .when()
          .replay().isEqual("ok")
          .setBody("<responsePart2>"+replay()+"</responsePart2>" + xpath("//part3")).inOut("http4://localhost/workingPart3")
        .otherwiese().to("activemq:error")
     .end()
  .otherwiese().to("activemq:error")
  .end()
```

Can you help me to find the right syntax?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is more than one possible solution for that:

```
ModelCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addRoutes(new RestBuilder("direct:rest1", "http4://localhost/workingPart1"));
context.addRoutes(new RestBuilder("direct:rest2", "http4://localhost/workingPart2"));
context.addRoutes(new RestBuilder("direct:rest3", "http4://localhost/workingPart3"));
context.addRoutes(new MainRouteBuilder());

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", XML);
```

The `RestBuilder` class:

```
public class RestBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private final String endpoint;
    private final String uri;
    public RestBuilder(final String endpoint, final String uri) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        this.uri = uri;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(endpoint)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
            .to(uri)
            .choice()
            .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isNotEqualTo(Integer.valueOf(200)))
            .throwException(new IllegalStateException());
    }
}
```

The `MainRouteBuilder` class:

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        onException(IllegalStateException.class)
            .log("Hm, no good")
            .to("activemq:error")
            .handled(true);

        from("direct:start")
            .setProperty("part1").xpath("/parts/part1/*")
            .setProperty("part2").xpath("/parts/part2/*")
            .setProperty("part3").xpath("/parts/part3/*")
            .setBody(simple("${property.part1}"))
            .to("direct:rest1")
            .setBody(simple("<responsePart1>${body}</responsePart1>${property.part2}"))
            .to("direct:rest2")
            .setBody(simple("<responsePart2>${body}</responsePart2>${property.part3}"))
            .to("direct:rest3");

    }
}
```